# Wagtail insert code into body (streamfield)

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

Is it possible to insert html in any other way than RawHTML? RawHTML is a threat and was wondering if I could do it another way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The threat is not specific to `RawHTMLBlock`. If you come up with another method of inserting arbitrary HTML, it will have exactly the same risks as `RawHTMLBlock` - namely, a malicious editor can insert harmful code. If you're happy to accept that risk, use `RawHTMLBlock`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
I might be making up stuff now but would it be possible to create a custom block in the streamfield to upload a CSV file that would be used for a d3 chart in the body? For example, have a custom block 'BarChart' rendered by a template, and the editor has to upload a CSV that would be used in the template to populate the chart with data? If it's possible, what should I be looking at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @gasman says in his comment on the question, inserting HTML carries the same risks no matter what form field you give your editors to do it.

However, you can implement a `.clean()` method on your block type which sanitises the HTML using [Bleach](https://github.com/mozilla/bleach).

e.g. to allow only `<p>` tags:

```py
>>> raw_html = """<p id='foo' class='dangerous'>
<script>console.log('bar');</script>
<b>Hello</b>
</p>"""
>>> html = bleach.clean(raw_html,
                        tags=['p'],
                        attributes={'p': ['id']},
                        strip=True)
>>> print(html)
<p id='foo'>Hello</p>
```